# Which is more efficient saving Files in cache or in device memory? Android

Tags: android, caching, storage, device

**Scenario**

I have made an application that displays a list of predefined products to the user. Each product has an image associated with it.

Initially to display the Image on the app, I had used ImageLoader which utilities the Image URL. But it takes up a lot of the users mobile-data.

To minimize the users mobile-data usages, I was planning to save the images on the users device when the app is installed and occasionally(once a month) when new items are added to the list.

**Question**

When the app is installed or if their are updates to certain image items is it better to download & save the images directly in the cache or as a hidden folder in the device storage ?

In my research I realized that

***In the cache*** : Lesser Viewed Images/Objects are evicted from the cache.

(I have a check in my code to see if the image to displayed is still in the storage, if not it will intern lead to downloading the image again.which i don't want)

***In the device storage***: It may not be ethical to hide Folder and Images on the device.

(the reason why the Images and Folder is hidden is because i don't want the user to view the images in their Galley or delete the folder by mistake)

**My Goal**

To ask your opinion for the best solution to the above scenario. 
Weather to save the images in the cache, device storage or some other method.

**My Aim**

How to minimize the users mobile-data usages.

Comment: use `Picasso` / `Glide` / `Volley` - i am almost sure they all have built-in cache support

Comment: It is unclear what you consider to be the/a cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Glide` or `Picasso` 3rd party libraries available which will reduce load time and once it is load it will cache image and display cache for next time.

Below is code to use

Add below in your **app.gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Source to load an image from URL into Imageview

```
 Picasso.get()
                .load("your image url")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.error)
                .fit()
                .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images of products are not updated frequently than you can save the images in the memory.

You can use the private folder of your application which is not shared by other application and the images which you saved is not displayed in the gallery.

The folder is inside the data/data/yourPackageName

You can get the path of the folder by below line:-
getApplicationInfo().dataDir

ImageLoader is using the cache memory to temparary save the images into your device so if the image is present in the cache it will not download again instead of that it will take from cache.

It totally depend upon you, if you save the images on the phisical storage and if their are too much images and you are not managing well than it might be possible that your application take to much memory of the device.

Hope it will help you.